# How to change twitter pfp via requests

Tags: twitter, python-requests

I would like to change twitter pfp via requests but NOT BY API

there is one parametr that describe whole image to upload:

[image]

and I dont understand where it takes place, maybe someone have already tried to do this and figured out?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `media_id` parameter is returned from the media upload API endpoint. You will need to use the Twitter API to accomplish this.